# Lining up polygon legend patches in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, legend

I have tried the properties and everything, I can't understand why my polygons are not lining up correctly in the legend.

I created this legend the usual way by adding my three layers to the legend wizard and creating the legend this way. It is only one legend, I've just recreated it and the same thing happens.

[image]

This is how I am creating my legend:

`Insert>legend>legend wizard (select 1 layer)> click defaults`

Comment: Do you have two legends nested together?

Comment: We'll need you to edit your questions to include more details like the precise steps you took to create your legend element(s) because this effect could be achieved in at least 2-3 ways.

Comment: I've noticed sometimes (with points mostly) that symbols wont line up properly in layout view. However, when exporting it looks good. Have you tried exporting and see what happens? A quick-and-dirty workaround is to convert to graphics and edit them manually, although that won't really solve the underlying problem.

Comment: It looks like you are using two different legends as for the upper two the labels are dark grey, whilst for the lower two the labels are black. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @Menno That could also be accomplished by using different fonts or styles for different layers. I agree that we need confirmation from the OP :)

Comment: they are just different font styles as I added the other two layers later, the same thing happens when I recreate the legend from scratch using the wizard. They are all polygon layers. On export they still don't line up.

Comment: By saying that "the same thing happens when I recreate the legend from scratch using the wizard" it sounds like you have a reproducible procedure that we could follow to see the same thing happen for us.  However, until you edit your question to describe those precise steps, it makes it hard for potential answerers to advise.  You may be surprised to find how often there is more than one "usual way" to do something.

Comment: insert>legend>legend wizard (select 1 layer)> click defaults

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem.  Is there something different about those two layers that are not lining up?  Is it always the same layers that don't line up?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two legends there?